# Is there a way to limit the frame-size of websockets on a browser?

Tags: browser, websocket

I'm building a websocket based web application, and I just ran across the Error: `Frame size of 77222 bytes exceeds maximum accepted frame size` on my server, which is then closing the websocket connection as a result. How can I tell the browser to limit the frame-size it uses for large websocket messages?

Comment: I think the browser expects the server to comply with the websocket specification. So I would definitely change the server component.

Comment: @vtortola I don't think the expectation is that every websocket server should be able to handle a frame of 18 million Terabytes. I would much sooner believe the browsers simply didn't think of this problem.

Comment: Well if the browser were able of sending that I guess it does :)